# Create datetime.time() object in yaml?

Tags: python, yaml

I know that I can create a `datetime.datetime` object and then use `.time()` method, like this:

`my_file.yaml`

```
MyDateTime: 2015-08-11 10:08:37
```

and then:

```
In [58]: f = open("my_file.yaml", "rU")

In [59]: temp = yaml.safe_load(f)

In [60]: f.close()

In [61]: temp['MyDateTime'].time()
Out[61]: datetime.time(10, 8, 37)
```

but that seems a little redundant, is there a way to create `datetime.time()` object to begin with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting custom class output in PyYAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744956/formatting-custom-class-output-in-pyyaml)

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200627/how-to-create-a-datetime-object-with-pyyaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the SafeLoader to do your bidding, but it is nicer to make a new Loader that does the same as the `SafeLoader` used by `safe_load()`.
The only thing you need to provide for that is a method that is invoked (`construct_yaml_time()`) when a timestamp scalar is matched and specify it by calling `add_constructor`.

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

from ruamel.yaml.loader import Reader, Scanner, Composer, SafeConstructor, \
     Resolver, Parser

class TimeConstructor(SafeConstructor):
    def __init__(self):
        SafeConstructor.__init__(self)

    def construct_yaml_time(self, node):
        x = SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_timestamp(self, node)
        return x.time()


TimeConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp',
    TimeConstructor.construct_yaml_time)

class TimeLoader(Reader, Scanner, Parser, Composer, TimeConstructor, Resolver):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        Reader.__init__(self, stream)
        Scanner.__init__(self)
        Parser.__init__(self)
        Composer.__init__(self)
        TimeConstructor.__init__(self)
        Resolver.__init__(self)

yaml_str = """\
MyDateTime: 2015-08-11 10:08:37
x: 23423
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=TimeLoader)
print data
```

gives you:

```
<type 'datetime.time'>
{'x': 23423, 'MyDateTime': datetime.time(10, 8, 37)}
```

---

You can also specify your time objects as `10:08:37` but this will load them as sexagesimal number and that will convert them to an integer (36517 in this case).  You can, of course, change this behaviour as well:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

from ruamel.yaml.loader import Reader, Scanner, Composer, SafeConstructor, \
     Resolver, Parser

import datetime

class TimeConstructor(SafeConstructor):
    def __init__(self):
        SafeConstructor.__init__(self)

    def construct_yaml_time(self, node):
        value = self.construct_scalar(node)
        if ':' not in value:
            return SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_int(self, node)
        return datetime.time(*[int(x) for x in value.split(':')])



TimeConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    TimeConstructor.construct_yaml_time)

class TimeLoader(Reader, Scanner, Parser, Composer, TimeConstructor, Resolver):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        Reader.__init__(self, stream)
        Scanner.__init__(self)
        Parser.__init__(self)
        Composer.__init__(self)
        TimeConstructor.__init__(self)
        Resolver.__init__(self)

yaml_str = """\
MyDateTime: 10:08:37
x: 12345
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=TimeLoader)
print data
```

which gives:

```
{'x': 12345, 'MyDateTime': datetime.time(10, 8, 37)}
```

This relies on the time to be recognised by the normal `int` recogniser. You can also recognise the sexagesimal itself, but that is more complex to implement in my experience.

---

Other alternatives exists, including creating `datetime.time` objects by tagging them explicitly **and** providing loading (and possible saving) routines.

Comment: I made the same mistake.  He's asking about getting a `datetime.time` object, not a `datetime.datetime` object. Fortunately, the question turns out to be a dupe with an existing good answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744956/formatting-custom-class-output-in-pyyaml

Comment: @larsks Thanks, I should not try to answer questions late at night after a long days work

Comment: Thanks, given your answer and the question larsks has linked to, it appears that there is no simple way to do this.

Comment: @Akavall No there is not, I provided an alternative, that allows you to write the time without the preceding date, but there is no built-in support for time objects as there is for datetimestamps and time duration (the sexagesimals).

Comment: Thank you for your help!